# How to analyze $A\cdot (\mathop{\rm tri} A)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have an upper triangular square matrix $A$,  and $\mathop{\rm tri}A$ is the operator which takes the tridiagonal part of $A$.  Assuming that we know ${\rm tri}(A)$ is invertible. I am trying to analyze the resulting square matrix of $A\cdot (\mathop{\rm tri} A)^{-1}$.    I checked a few example, the result would have 0 on the tridiagonal places except the diagonals which has 1.

For example : 
A =

```
0.8635    0.0616    0.4681    0.8341    0.5630
     0    0.0453    0.2847    0.0023    0.0300
     0         0    0.8531    0.8530    0.8728
     0         0         0    0.4691    0.4384
     0         0         0         0    0.7152
```

B =

```
0.8635    0.0616         0         0         0
     0    0.0453    0.2847         0         0
     0         0    0.8531    0.8530         0
     0         0         0    0.4691    0.4384
     0         0         0         0    0.7152
```

A*inv(B) =

```
1.0000         0    0.5488    0.7803    0.3090
     0    1.0000         0    0.0048    0.0390
     0         0    1.0000         0    1.2204
     0         0         0    1.0000   -0.0000
     0         0         0         0    1.0000
```

I wonder how can I prove it ?  I try to come up with a proof,  however it seems hard to analyze the formula because there is the $\mathop{\rm tri}$ operator, which it is not related with anything else.

Could you guys give me some suggestions what I should do first?  I also wonder if I can try to write it as a series of a linear transformation through matrix multiplication (${\rm tri}(A) = PAQ$ for example).

More generally I want to know what people usually do when encounter problem having this type of placement operator on their matrices?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume your matrix is square since you write $tri(A)^{-1}$. Well if you took a basis for $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}$ consisting of the matrices $E_{ij}$ where there is a $1$ at the $ij^{\text{th}}$ position and zeros elsewhere, then $tri( - )$ is just a projection of $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}$ onto itself (sending the components of $E_{ij}$ with $|i-j| > 1$ to zero). In this sense it is a linear transformation "on $A$". You seem to want to write $tri(A) = TA$ for some matrix $T \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}$. Am I right?

Comment: Also, what property exactly do you want to analyze? (And how do you know $\mathrm{tri}(A)$ is invertible?..)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : thanks a lot for your help Patrick.  I see that it is a linear transformation now.  Yes the linear transformation I mean is by pre-multiplying or after-multiplying A with another matrix.   Actually the only reason I want to do it that way is because it seems hard to analyze the behavior on $tri(-)$.  Could you please give me some suggestion if I want to say something about $A\cdot (\mathop{\rm tri} A)^{-1}$,  how should I start ?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I modified my original problem.  It is assumed $tri(A)$ is invertible.   I want to know what the result would look like.  A few numerically testing case says that it would give a matrix with 1 on the diagonal and 0 on the neighboring, and none zero on other entries.  But I want to come up with a proof for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hypothesis:

> I checked a few example, the result would have 0 on the tridiagonal places except the diagonals which has 1.

seems wrong to me. To test it, I made the following Mathematica code:

```
n = 4;
tri[A_] := Table[
   If[Abs[i - j] <= 1, A[[i, j]], 0],
   {i, 1, Length[A]}, {j, 1, Length[A[[1]]]}];
Print["Random matrix"]
(A = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
tri[A] // MatrixForm
A.Inverse[tri[A]] // Chop // MatrixForm
Print["Symmetric matrix"]
(A = A + Transpose[A]) // MatrixForm
tri[A] // MatrixForm
A.Inverse[tri[A]] // Chop // MatrixForm
```

Here is the "random matrix" part of one run (with my denotations):

\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{bmatrix}
 1.69343 & -1.76162 & 1.98051 & -0.576296 \\
 -0.0443134 & -0.827581 & -1.88169 & 1.50973 \\
 1.75242 & -0.238351 & -0.423953 & -1.16802 \\
 -0.304704 & 1.88461 & -1.0754 & -0.801786
\end{bmatrix}\!, \\
\mathop{\rm tri}A &= \begin{bmatrix}
 1.69343 & -1.76162 & 0 & 0 \\
 -0.0443134 & -0.827581 & -1.88169 & 0 \\
 0 & -0.238351 & -0.423953 & -1.16802 \\
 0 & 0 & -1.0754 & -0.801786
\end{bmatrix}\!, \\
A(\mathop{\rm tri}A)^{-1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
 0.98813 & -0.45361 & 1.66272 & -1.70344 \\
 0.00872935 & 1.33359 & -1.22278 & -0.101648 \\
 0.997163 & -1.43975 & -1.37092 & 3.4539 \\
 -0.212331 & -1.23807 & -2.03881 & 3.97009
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

I got the same "no obvious rule" result for the symmetric part, so I won't clutter this with any more random numbers.

The thing is, I got this on many repeats. Sure, $n = 3$ gives a nicer result (middle row $A(\mathop{\rm tri}A)^{-1}$ gets to be $e_2^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$), but this is normal, since $\mathop{\rm tri}A$ has the same middle row and column as $A$. Even if I use `RandomInteger[]` instead of `RandomReal[]` (with the same very small range $[-2,2]$), I get random, not "nice" results.

I am not saying that there are absolutely no "nice" properties to this, but I'm quite sure they're not very obvious.

As for the $PAQ$-representation, you can use
$$\mathop{\rm tri}A = \sum_{|i-j| \le 1} E_i A E_j,$$
where $E_k$ is a null-matrix with $1$ on the position $(k,k)$. However, I don't think this will help you much.

**Edit** (the triangular case)

Note that, when $A$ is triangular, $A$ and $B := \mathop{\rm tri} A$ have the same determinant. Now, use the [adjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\mathop{\rm adj} A$ of $A$.

You should be able to prove that $\mathop{\rm adj} A$ and $\mathop{\rm adj} B$ coincide on the band of width $1$ (i.e., on the diagonal, the subdiagonal, and the superdiagonal).

Now, use the formula for the matrix inverse via adjugate (on the same link) and you should be able to prove your hypothesis.

Comment: Vedran Sego:  Thanks a lot for your help.  Sorry it seems that only for upper triangular matrix this property holds. I didn't notice I was playing with upper triangular matrices all the time.  I modified my question and put an example in the question.

Comment: In that case, you may be right. See my edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Vedran! that's a nice way to prove.  I will try it.

Comment: It just occurred to me: also use the fact that the inverse of the triangular matrix is again triangular. This will give you that all the minors $A_{ij}$, when $i > j$ are zero. When $i = j$ or $i = j-1$, the $ij$-adjugate is triangular, so its determinant is obviously identical in for both matrices (it's just a product of the elements on the diagonal). This should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I just come up the proof with the same fact now.  Thanks a lot